# Можно ли нарисовать слово?

Tags: семантика

В смысле буквами, а не то значение, которое это слово несет. Скажем, в приложении (в *Крокодиле*), где требуется отгадать загаданное слово, не рисуя на холсте само это слово, а лишь изображая с помощью карандаша ассоциацию. Так вот, если я вместо ассоциации нарисую на холсте само слово (по сути, нарушу правила), то я все-таки **нарисую** это слово или **напишу** его?

Comment: Слово не нарисовать - напишете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте набрать в любом поисковике "нарисованное слово". Например, в [Яндексе](https://yandex.ru/images/search?text=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE).
Вы увидите множество рисунков, про которые очень трудно сказать, что слово "написано". Оно именно "нарисовано".
А значит формулировка "нарисую слово" вполне уместна в отношении не только обозначаемого словом предмета, но и самого слова.

Comment: Рисование слова - это нечто новое! Вот буквы можно рисовать, но слово, хоть вязанное, хоть выпиленное - написано.

Comment: @Нижегородец, а Вы пройдите по ссылке из моего ответа, и увидите множество именно нарисованных слов.

Comment: не слов, а букв... слово пишется рисованными буквами

Comment: @Нижегородец, комбинации нарисованных букв образуют нарисованные слова.

Comment: :) рисование букв и сложение их в слова - это и есть - писание, а не рисование... хоть вы упритесь, но это так

Comment: @Нижегородец, Если "писание" - в смысле "писать картину", тогда да.

Comment: вот видите, даже картину - пишет

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91426/discussion-between-ivan-olshansky-and-).